# Angularjs - Resharper intellisense broken with TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, resharper, intellisense, definitelytyped

I have VS 2013 Update 4, TS 1.4, latest WebEssentials and R# 8.
I am trying to create some AngularJS code in my MVC solution.
In installed Angularjs and angular.d.ts via nuget. I have done the same for "marked" and also jQuery installed automatically as Angular dependency.

How, none of Angular types get resolved by Intellisense. If I am trying to type "mar" in an empty TypeScript file I get this:
[image]

If I type "jque" I get this:
[image]

But when I type "ang" - nothing.
[image]

All d.ts files are in place:
[image]

Adding reference path directive does not help, although it is not required and Intellisense works perfectly fine for other frameworks. Manual typing without Intellisense support works fine and I get no compilation errors, so TSLint and tsc are ok with my code.

So, my question is - what is going on there?

P.S. Just added Knockout to test this and typing "ko" brings proper Intellisense.

P.P.S. I turned off the TS support in R# and intellisense seems to work properly. So, I would assume this is the Resharper issue.

Comment: This shows you how to add intelisense: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/05/using-angularjs-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: @WayneEllery As I wrote, the standard Intellisense works OK.

Comment: You're welcome to try [ReSharper 9.1 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.1+EAP) and check whether it fixes your problem. If not, please [report an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=Type+Bug&c=Affected+Wave+Wave+02+EAP+2&c=Subsystem+TypeScript). Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I turned off the TS support in R# and intellisense seems to work properly. So, I would assume this is the Resharper issue

Yes. They need to update for `v1.4` of typescript. You can use an older `angular.d.ts` till then : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1.3.0/angularjs/angular.d.ts

Comment: Right. They also replied to my support ticket that TS 1.4 will be supported in R# 9.1.

Comment: You can download and try out RS 9.1 here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.1+EAP Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

As basart mentioned, rather than installing EAP or turning Resharper off, you can use an older version of the file for the interim period. But I advise against adding it manually in your solution. [Version 1.7.4 of jQuery d.ts](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/1.7.4) and [version 2.4.0 of Angular d.ts](http://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/2.4.0) worked for me and you can use NuGet from the Package Manager command line in Visual Studio to install them.

```
Install-Package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -Version 1.7.4
Install-Package angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -Version 2.4.0
```

Make sure you select your project in the dropdown box inside the console before running the command.

Comment: This is the same answer as the one from basarat

Comment: Who keeps files downloaded by hand nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a little earlier today, where inline intellisense was flagging `angular`, as well as various interfaces (usually `IPromise<T>`) as not being found, despite having reference metacomments and the files present in my project.

Similar to the answer from @basarat, I was able to disable ReSharper Intellisense (Resharper | Options... | Intellisense | General), restart Visual Studio, and then re-enable TypeScript Intellisense.  Upon re-enabling intellisense, I no longer get red squigglies.

I did this in Visual Studio 2015, ReSharper 2016.3.2, on a project that is using Angular 1.6 and TypeScript together, with no `tsconfig.json` file (configuration is done in the TypeScript tab of the Web project.)